# A symbolic formula / closed form for Dirichlet inversion?

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, dirichlet-convolution

On compting the dirichlet inverse $f^{-1}(pqrs)$ where I assumed $(p, q, r, s)$ to be arbitrary primes, I arrived at the formula:

#### $(p, q, r, s)$

$$
f^{-1}(pqrs) = 24f(p)f(q)f(r)f(s)/f(1)^5 + \\
-6f(p)f(q)f(rs)/f(1)^4 + 
-6f(p)f(qr)f(s)/f(1)^4 + 
-6f(pq)f(r)f(s)/f(1)^4 + \\
-6f(pr)f(q)f(s)/f(1)^4 +
-6f(p)f(qs)f(r)/f(1)^4 +
-6f(ps)f(q)f(r)/f(1)^4 + \\
\mathbf{2f(p)f(qrs)/f(1)^3} +
2f(pq)f(rs)/f(1)^3 +
2f(pqr)f(s)/f(1)^3 + \\
2f(pqs)f(r)/f(1)^3 +
\mathbf{2f(pr)f(qs)/f(1)^3} +
2f(prs)f(q)/f(1)^3 + \\
2f(ps)f(qr)/f(1)^3 + \\
-1f(pqrs)/f(1)^2
$$

This was done using code so I'm fairly sure it's correct. What I don't understand **is what this is counting**. Why are  there terms that have both groupings of 2-and-2, as well as groupings of 1-and-3? What is the genral pattern here? Clearly $n!$ is involved, as well as what I thought were ${k}\choose{r}$, but that cannot be since we have groups of **unequal size**.

Can someone please explain to me what is going on, a proof of **what this is counting**, and what the **general formula** is for primes $p_0 p_1 \dots p_n$?

#### Formal details

the Dirichlet convolution of two functions is defined as:

$$
f, g: \mathbb Z \rightarrow \mathbb C \qquad
(f \star g)(n) \equiv \sum_{d|n} f(d) g\left(\frac{n}{d}\right)
$$

We can define the inverse function of $f$ with respect to the Dirichlet convolution as the unique function $f^{-1}$ that satisfies the identity 
$$
(f \star f^{-1})(n) \equiv
\begin{cases}
1 & \text{if $n=1$} \\ 0 &\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

We can compute this recursively as:

\begin{align*}
f^{-1}(1) &= \frac{1}{f(1)} \\
f^{-1}(n) &= \frac{-1}{f(1)} \sum_{d|n~d<n}f\left(\frac{n}{d}\right)f^{-1}(d)
\end{align*}

This allows one to *symbolically* compute $f^{-1}(n)$ for choices of primes.  I did this for primes called $p, q, r, s$. The results are:

#### $(p, q)$

$$
f^{-1}(p, q)  = 2f(p)f(q)/f(1)^3 +
-1f(pq)/f(1)^2
$$

### $(p, q, r)$

$$
f(p, q, r) = -6f(p)f(q)f(r)/f(1)^4 + \\
2f(p)f(qr)/f(1)^3 +
2f(pq)f(r)/f(1)^3 +
2f(pr)f(q)/f(1)^3 + \\
-1f(pqr)/f(1)^2
$$

Upto this point, one can harbour hope that it is indeed the binomial coefficients, but the part posted above shows that this is not the case, hence the question.

[Full code listing available here, written in Haskell](https://gist.github.com/bollu/f23a6056242ecdda632246acc95e2509)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What the coefficients count are the number of ordered factorisations of $n$ corresponding to a [multiplicative partition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_partition) of $n$.

An ordered factorisation of $n$ with $k$ factors is a(n ordered) $k$-tuple $(d_1, \dotsc, d_k)$ of integers $d_{\kappa} \geqslant 2$ such that
$$n = \prod_{\kappa = 1}^{k} d_{\kappa}\,.$$
Let us denote the set of all ordered factorisations of $n$ with $k$ factors by $OF(n,k)$. It is easy to see that $OF(n,k) = \varnothing$ for $k > \Omega(n)$ (the number of prime factors of $n$ counted with multiplicity), and $OF(n,0) = \varnothing$
for $n > 1$, while $OF(1,0) = \{()\}$ is the singleton set containing the $0$-tuple $()$.

Now let us first find an expression for $f^{-1}(n)$ in terms of ordered factorisations of $n$. Iterating from the fundamental
$$f^{-1}(n) = -\frac{1}{f(1)}\sum_{\substack{d \mid n \\ d > 1}} f(d)f^{-1}\biggl(\frac{n}{d}\biggr) \tag{1}$$
for $n > 1$, we obtain
$$f^{-1}(n) = \sum_{k = 0}^{\Omega(n)} \frac{(-1)^k}{f(1)^{k+1}} \sum_{(d_1,\dotsc, d_k) \in OF(n,k)} \prod_{\kappa = 1}^{k} f(d_{\kappa})\,. \tag{2}$$
We prove $(2)$ by induction.

For $n = 1$, $\Omega(n) = 0$ and the right hand side of $(2)$ evaluates to $1/f(1)$, which indeed is $f^{-1}(1)$.

Let now $n > 1$, and assume $(2)$ already established for all $m < n$. By $(1)$, we have
$$f^{-1}(n) = -\frac{1}{f(1)}\sum_{\substack{d \mid n \\ d > 1}} f(d)f^{-1}\biggl(\frac{n}{d}\biggr)\,.$$
There the arguments of $f^{-1}$ on the right hand side are all $< n$, hence by the induction hypothesis
\begin{align}
f^{-1}(n) &= -\frac{1}{f(1)}\sum_{\substack{d \mid n \\ d > 1}} f(d) \sum_{k = 0}^{\Omega(n/d)} \frac{(-1)^k}{f(1)^{k+1}}\sum_{OF(n/d,k)} \prod_{\kappa = 1}^{k} f(d_{\kappa}) \\
&= \sum_{\substack{d\mid n \\ d > 1}} \sum_{k = 0}^{\Omega(n/d)} \frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{f(1)^{k+2}}\sum_{OF(n/d,k)} f(d)\prod_{\kappa = 1}^{k} f(d_{\kappa})\,.
\end{align}
Now, since $OF(n/d,k) = \varnothing$ for $k > \Omega(n/d)$ we can extend the second sum to $\Omega(n)-1 \geqslant \Omega(n/d)$ without changing the value, and then change the order of summation to obtain
\begin{align}
f^{-1}(n)
&= \sum_{\substack{d\mid n \\ d > 1}} \sum_{k = 0}^{\Omega(n)-1} \frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{f(1)^{k+2}}\sum_{OF(n/d,k)} f(d)\prod_{\kappa = 1}^{k} f(d_{\kappa}) \\
&= \sum_{k = 0}^{\Omega(n)-1} \frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{f(1)^{k+2}} \sum_{\substack{d\mid n \\ d > 1}}\sum_{OF(n/d,k)} f(d)\prod_{\kappa = 1}^{k} f(d_{\kappa})\,.
\end{align}
The map $(d,(d_1,\dotsc,d_k)) \mapsto (d,d_1,\dotsc,d_k)$ gives a bijection from
$$\bigcup_{\substack{d \mid n \\ d > 1}} \{d\} \times OF(n/d,k)$$
to $OF(n,k+1)$, thus
\begin{align}
f^{-1}(n) &= \sum_{k = 0}^{\Omega(n)-1} \frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{f(1)^{k+2}} \sum_{\substack{d\mid n \\ d > 1}}\sum_{OF(n/d,k)} f(d)\prod_{\kappa = 1}^{k} f(d_{\kappa}) \\
&= \sum_{k = 0}^{\Omega(n)-1} \frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{f(1)^{k+2}} \sum_{OF(n,k+1)} \prod_{\kappa = 1}^{k+1}f(d_{\kappa}) \\
&= \sum_{k = 1}^{\Omega(n)} \frac{(-1)^k}{f(1)^{k+1}} \sum_{OF(n,k)} \prod_{\kappa = 1}^{k} f(d_{\kappa}) \\
&= \sum_{k = 0}^{\Omega(n)} \frac{(-1)^k}{f(1)^{k+1}} \sum_{OF(n,k)} \prod_{\kappa = 1}^{k} f(d_{\kappa})
\end{align}
where we reindexed in the penultimate line and used $OF(n,0) = \varnothing$ for $n > 1$ in the last. Thus $(2)$ also holds for $n$, and our induction proof is complete.

The product $\prod_{\kappa = 1}^{k} f(d_{\kappa})$ of course depends only on how often each divisor of $n$ occurs in the $k$-tuple $(d_1, \dotsc, d_k)$ and not on the order in which they occur. Thus we can collect all the $k$-tuples that can obtained from each other by a permutation of the components into one group. Such a group corresponds to a multiplicative partition of $n$.

We can view a multiplicative partition of $n$ as a function
$$u \colon D'(n) \to \mathbb{N}\cup \{0\}$$
such that
$$\prod_{d \in D'(n)} d^{u(d)} = n\,,$$
where $D'(n) = \{ d : d \mid n, d > 1\}$. Let $MP(n)$ be the set of all multiplicative partitions of $n$, and for $u \in MP(n)$ let
$$\sigma(u) = \sum_{d \in D'(n)} u(d)\,,$$
that is, $\sigma(u)$ is the number of factors in the partition. The number of ordered factorisations of $n$ corresponding to the multiplicative partition $u$ is
$$N(u) := \frac{\sigma(u)!}{\prod_{d \in D'(n)} u(d)!}$$
and therefore we can express the formula for $f^{-1}(n)$ in terms of multiplicative partitions of $n$ as
$$f^{-1}(n) = \sum_{u \in MP(n)} \frac{(-1)^{\sigma(u)}}{f(1)^{\sigma(u)+1}}\cdot N(u) \prod_{d \in D'(n)} f(d)^{u(d)}\,. \tag{3}$$
If $n$ is squarefree, a multiplicative partition of $n$ cannot have two equal factors, and thus $N(u)$ is simply $\sigma(u)!$ in that case.

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to read this tonight and accept the answer once I understand it :) Is there a "high-brow" way to "see"/derive this interpretation, without having to go through the induction?

Comment: Yes, there is a high-brow way. Consider the Dirichlet series with coefficients $f(n)$, $$F(s) = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{f(n)}{n^s}\,.$$ If that's not convergent anywhere, view it as a formal Dirichlet series. The Dirichlet series with coefficients $f^{-1}(n)$ is the reciprocal of $F$, $$\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{f^{-1}(n)}{n^s} = \frac{1}{F(s)} = \frac{1}{f(1) + R(s)}\,,$$ where $$R(s) = \sum_{n = 2}^{\infty} \frac{f(n)}{n^s}\,.$$ Now you can expand the last in a geometric series,

Comment: $$\frac{1}{f(1)+R(s)}=f(1)^{-1}\frac{1}{1+f(1)^{-1}R(s)}=f(1)^{-1}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (-1)^k\biggl(\frac{R(s)}{f(1)}\biggr)^k\,.$$ Then you look at the coefficient of $\frac{1}{n^s}$ in each $R(s)^k$. It is — at least if you know where you want to end up — not too difficult to see that it is $$\sum_{OF(n,k)} \prod_{\kappa = 1}^{k} f(d_{\kappa})\,.$$ But I took a lower-brow route, I asked myself "where do I end up if I iterate $(1)$?". It may be worth pointing out that these formulæ aren't practically useful. The number of multiplicative partitions of $n$ grows far too quickly with $\Omega(n)$.